# Arithmetic Progressions in Abstract Root Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection, root-systems

I'm interested in proving part (2) of Theorem 10 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06ci-linear-algebra-communications-intensive-spring-2004/projects/rs2.pdf):

> Let $\Delta$ be an abstract root system in [a finite dimensional Euclidean space] $V$.
>
> (1)  If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $\Delta$, and $\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle>0$, then $\alpha-\beta$ is a root or $0$. If $\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle<0$, then $\alpha+\beta$ is a root or $0$.
>
> (2) If $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Delta \cup \{0\}$, then the set of elements of $\Delta \cup \{0\}$ of the form $\beta+n \alpha$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, contains all and only such elements with $-p \leq n \leq q$, for some $p \geq 0$ and $q \geq 0$ such that $p-q = \frac{2\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle}{\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle}$.
>
> Hint: To prove (2), assume there is a gap in the set of elements of $\Delta \cup \{0\}$ of the form $\beta + n \alpha$ and use (1) to get a contradiction.

Here is my attempt at part (2):

Let
$$S:=\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:\beta + n \alpha \in \Delta\}.$$
As the root system $\Delta$ is finite, so is $S$. Moreover, it is evident that $0 \in S$. Hence we may define
$$ -p:=\min S \leq 0, \\ q:=\max S \geq 0. $$

The inner product
$$\langle \beta+n \alpha,\alpha \rangle=\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle+n \langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle \tag{$\star$} $$
is positive when $n>-\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle/\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle$ and negative when $n>-\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle/\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle$. It could be zero if $n^*:=-\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle/\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle$ is an integer. Now we prove by cases:

- If $-p=q$ then both must be zero, and the result is obvious.
- If $-p<q$, we can repeatedly apply part (1), starting from both endpoints $n=-p$ and $n=q$ (unless one of them is equal to $n^*$, in which case the other endpoint alone suffices).

In any case, we have shown that $\beta+n \alpha \in \Delta$ for all $-p \leq n \leq q$. The only thing missing is showing that $p-q = \frac{2\langle \beta,\alpha \rangle}{\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle}$.

Is my proof correct? Any hints on the final part? Thank you!

Comment: Looks ok to me. Part (2) needs the fact that the chain of roots from $\beta-p\alpha$ to $\beta+q\alpha$ must be stable under the reflection w.r.t. the hyperplane orthogonal to $\alpha$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the confirmation. Is the comment about stability under the reflection regarding the $p-q$ part at the end? If so, I can't quite see how.

Comment: Let $\alpha_1=\beta-p\alpha$, $\alpha_2=\beta+q\alpha$. Because $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the endpoints of that chain, stability under that reflection implies $\langle \alpha_1,\alpha\rangle=-\langle\alpha_2,\alpha\rangle$.